# Bootstrap chef workstation

Tags: chef-infra

Is there an easy way to bootstrap a Chef workstation, just like you bootstrap a node?

Would be so much more convenient than copying the ssh keys to the right directory with the right name and permissions, running knife configure, etc...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700194/to-setup-chef-workstation/21712350#21712350

Answer (score 0):

A chef workstation is a chef node as well, no difference on the bootstrap.

The only difference are:

- chef workstation client is privileged as administrator, which you can grant it via knife or chef server UI.
- `~/.chef/knife.rb` you can write a recipe to do it.

Comment: Only theoretically. Chef normal bootstrap doesn't copy the webui.pem, doesn't configure the chef node properly as a workstation, and at least the last time I tinkered with it, had a weird naming conventions that were different than from the guide.