# Any way to generate and get validation key from chef server?

Tags: chef-infra

Currently I'm quite new to Chef. I have install Chef server. But I wish to knife bootstrap from my workstation to Chef Server. But it appear to have error that private key could not be loaded. I'm not too sure where to get the Private key and chef-validate.pem .

All using command line, so I quite lost now.

After I have state the 1st part to get the validation key,

> chef-server-ctl user-create user_name first_name last_name email password

it shown 
ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from /etc/opscode/pivotal.pem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700194/to-setup-chef-workstation/21712350#21712350

Answer (score 2):

You have to be root to execute the chef-server-ctl user-create command. Have a look here: https://docs.chef.io/install_server.html#standalone

Comment: It does not say to be root anywhere on that page.

Answer (score 1):

For /etc/opscode/pivotal.pem is missing error use following command.

cp /opt/opscode/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/spec/fixtures/pivotal.pem  /etc/opscode/

Answer (score 0):

The validation key should be on your server under `/etc/chef-server`

You'll have to run a `knife configure` on your workstation with access to the validation key.

Once that done you'll be able to do a `knife bootstrap` of any other node which will install chef-client and make a client.rb with the informations from your knife.rb file.

See [this doc](http://docs.getchef.com/knife_configure.html) for the configure command of knife.

Edit after comment:

Documentation on the steps neede on chef 12 is [here](http://docs.getchef.com/install_server.html)

Brief quote you have to:
`chef-server-ctl user-create user_name first_name last_name email password` which will return the rsa key for the user which will be you validation key at end

`chef-server-ctl org-create short_name full_organization_name --association_user user_name` To create your organization and associate the previous user as the validation user to be used later for registering users/nodes etc.

Comment: Thanks for replying. As my server doesn't have /etc/chef-server. So I can't manage to find the validation key. How do I get /etc/chef-server ? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, because I install Chef Server 12 on Ubuntu 14.04, is it the reason that I do not have the Chef Server Folder?

Comment: Yes, in chef server 12 you have to create an organization and a validation client.rb this organization, I'll try to find the doc once at work.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I will try it out and see it works for my side. Thanks once again.

Comment: After I have state the 1st part to get the validation key, it shown ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from /etc/opscode/pivotal.pem

Comment: Edit your question whith erros got when generating keys and so on. Comments are not a good idea to work with. You may find some help on irc.freenode.net on channel #chef too for this kind of support, Chef 12 is still in release candidate state.

Comment: Where is the "public" validator.pem file for Chef 12 store? It's not in /etc/chef-server (that directory doesn't even exist).

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to create an organization
next you'll need to create a user and associate him to the org

then:
Log into the chef server
Create a user for yourself
Download starter kit (or regenerate it)
Use admin user to add yourself to the org.
Then bootstrap :)

Then you will be able to bootstrap nodes to the org using the validation key.

```
$ chef-server-ctl user-create user_name first_name last_name email password --filename FILE_NAME
$ chef-server-ctl org-create short_name "full_organization_name" --association_user user_name --filename ORGANIZATION-validator.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error few months back. The pivotal user pem key is stored at "/opt/opscode/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/spec/fixtures/pivotal.pem"
location. Just copy it to /etc/opscode.

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://flugel.it/devops/chef-how-to-regenerate-the-validation-key/) worked for me in an 12.x Chef Server.

```
knife client delete --delete-validators org-validator
knife client create org-validator --validator -f file_roots/chef-client/files/chef-validator-linode.pem
```