# Chef workstation error

Tags: chef-infra

I have set up the chef server and workstation before, configured nodes to it, run recipes and worked on chef. But recently i have been facing this issue, that has been troubling me from the past few days.

When i run the command for setting up **workstation**,

`knife configure -i`

the prompt asks us to enter the details of location of pem files and server FQDN and etc.

Below is the error:

```
[root@chef-server .chef]# knife configure -i
Overwrite /root/.chef/knife.rb? (Y/N) Y
Please enter the chef server URL: [https://myserver.example.com:443]
Please enter a name for the new user: [root] anyuser
Please enter the existing admin name: [admin]
Please enter the location of the existing admin's private key: [/etc/chef-server/admin.pem] ~/.chef/admin.pem
Please enter the validation clientname: [chef-validator]
Please enter the location of the validation key: [/etc/chef-server/chef-validator.pem] ~/.chef/chef-validator.pem
Please enter the path to a chef repository (or leave blank):
Creating initial API user...
Please enter a password for the new user:
ERROR: Service temporarily unavailable
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:325:in `stream_check': undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:199:in `read_body'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http/response.rb:226:in `body'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:502:in `rescue in format_rest_error'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:500:in `format_rest_error'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:480:in `humanize_http_exception'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:430:in `humanize_exception'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:421:in `rescue in run_with_pretty_exceptions'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:412:in `run_with_pretty_exceptions'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/knife.rb:213:in `run'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:139:in `run'
        from /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/bin/knife:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/bin/knife:40:in `load'
        from /usr/bin/knife:40:in `<main>'
```

This is the trace. 
Thanks.

Comment: If this is a new Chef Server you should _really_ be using Chef Server 12, and notably knife configure is not compatible with Chef Server 12.

Comment: @coderanger :[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191009/chef-server-does-not-generate-admin-pem) please check the link, i have been facinf issues using the chef 12 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of chef are you using? I wonder if you are experiencing [CHEF-4010](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4010) which is a problem registering a new user. (The "-i" parameter to knife command).

As a work-around for Chef Server 11 I can suggest using the pre-configured "admin" user on your chef server. See:

- [To setup chef workstation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700194/to-setup-chef-workstation/21712350#21712350)

Comment: thanks a lot, that helped, but i would like to know what this error was and what solved the issue. instead of parameters prompted by knife, we used our own parameters. i wonder how it did not prompt for passwd which created issue.

Comment: @vikramiyer The "-i" parameter creates a new user on the chef server. That was why I asked what version of chef you are using (CHEF-4010 fixed in version 11.6.0). The work-around I suggested uses the "admin" user that exists on all new chef servers, explaining why you were not prompted for a password.

Comment: nicely explained! :) Now, when i am trying to register a node(client) to the server, it throws the following error.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689327/chef-node-not-registering-with-server)

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes this error occurs because of proxies.
Simply unset the proxies:

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
```