# Chef node not registering with server

Tags: centos, chef-infra

I am trying to register my client to the server, but it gives following error on running below command:

**`[root@vm ~]# chef-client -S https://chef-server.example.com -K /etc/chef/chef-validator.pem`**

```
{:config_missing=>true}
[2014-12-29T18:20:00+05:30] WARN: *****************************************
[2014-12-29T18:20:00+05:30] WARN: Did not find config file: /etc/chef/client.rb, using command line options.
[2014-12-29T18:20:00+05:30] WARN: *****************************************
Starting Chef Client, version 12.0.3
Creating a new client identity for vm.example.com using the validator key.
[2014-12-29T18:20:01+05:30] WARN: Failed to register new client, 4 tries remaining
[2014-12-29T18:20:01+05:30] WARN: Response: HTTP 503 - 503 "Service Unavailable"
[2014-12-29T18:20:01+05:30] WARN: Failed to register new client, 3 tries remaining
[2014-12-29T18:20:01+05:30] WARN: Response: HTTP 503 - 503 "Service Unavailable"
[2014-12-29T18:20:01+05:30] WARN: Failed to register new client, 2 tries remaining
[2014-12-29T18:20:01+05:30] WARN: Response: HTTP 503 - 503 "Service Unavailable"
[2014-12-29T18:20:01+05:30] WARN: Failed to register new client, 1 tries remaining
[2014-12-29T18:20:01+05:30] WARN: Response: HTTP 503 - 503 "Service Unavailable"
[2014-12-29T18:20:01+05:30] WARN: Failed to register new client, 0 tries remaining
[2014-12-29T18:20:01+05:30] WARN: Response: HTTP 503 - 503 "Service Unavailable"
[2014-12-29T18:20:01+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 1.180742976 seconds
[2014-12-29T18:20:01+05:30] ERROR: undefined method `closed?' for nil:NilClass
[2014-12-29T18:20:01+05:30] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: You should create a client.rb file (in /etc/chef) anyway where you'll set the chef server url, validator key path and validator name too. Here it looks like your chef-server is not available as you get a 503 response from it (I assume there's no load balancer nor proxy involved in the line), but it's a guess as I've no idea wich version of chef server you're using. Check your chef-server logs with `chef-server-ctl tail` , it may be that your did not specify the validator name too but I would expect the server to answer with a 403 not authorized instead...

Comment: As Tensibai pointed out there is a warning that you chef client cannot find its configuration file "/etc/chef/client.rb". "knife bootstrap" from your chef workstation is the recommended way to get your chef client working. It will login over SSH, install chef-client, configure it (create the "/etc/chef/client.rb" file) and finally run it against your chef server. As @Tensibai pointed out this still doesn't explain a 503 error but it's a start. Finally the log output indicates you're using chef 12.. but what version of chef server are you using?

Comment: i am using chef-server version 11.0.8-1. Is there any compatibility issue if a higher version of client is used against server??
As far as i have set up the nodes before, i use the above command and register the client and later i create the client.rb file and edit the contents. 
it has worked for me, waiting for your answer.

Comment: Indeed, there's been some problems between chef-client 12 and chef-server 11, I would stick with a 11.16 chef-client if your server is still in 11 for now... I remember a blog post about a parameter to set on enterprise chef server (if you're using it and not open source one)

Comment: The above comment is incorrect, Chef Server 11 and Chef Client 12 are compatible with each other.

Comment: @coderanger I can swear I can't connect a chef-client 12.0.0 or 12.0.1 with my open source chef-server 11.0.4 and I get 503 errors (as per Noah mail on the mailing list, it seems there is problems between chef-client 12 and OS chef-server < 11.1).

Comment: Correcting myself, it was a mail from Mark Mzyk talking about the upgrade for the server. But I maintain what I said about client in 12 and server in 11.0.x. Quote from Mark: "Upgrading to 11.1+ will also help when you transition to 12, since the upgrade process to get to 12 is designed for 11.1+ and is known to not currently work with older versions of the server."

Comment: Any update on this? How did you solve this, I am encountering the same issue with Chef Server 12, and Client 12.x.x

Answer (score 1):

I exactly encountered same issue and after struggling some time, I found out that it is a proxy problem.

I am behind a corporate proxy and the error I got "503: Service Unavailable" is not something coming from Chef Server, rather it is coming from the proxy server.

Anyway, using "no_proxy" option and adding Chef Server's fqdn solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure knife commands from your workstation are working first. `knife client list` is a basic one you can use to test your server installation. It sounds like Chef Server is not installed correctly or was unable to start some components.

Comment: **knife client list**,  **knife user list** work fine. so i suppose the server and workstation have been setup correctly.