# Chef-Server does not generate admin.pem

Tags: chef-infra

I have used chef version 11 without any issues. Now that I hear the new version 12 is out, I wanted to use the same.
So, on a fresh aws instance I downloaded the **chef-server-core-12.0.0-1** installed it right away.
Now going forward, I used the command,

```
chef-server-ctl reconfigure
```

to start all the services as mentioned in the official document.
Now this step should also create a new admin, a validator that will be used in **knife.rb**. This was taken care of in the chef version 11.
Now I am unable to generate the **admin.pem** and **chef-validator.pem** without which I cannot setup a new workstation.

Answer (score 0):

I can't do more than give you the documentation link:

http://docs.chef.io/install_server.html#standalone

Read carefully and you'll see you have to create the first organization and first admin for this organization (steps 5 and 6).

Chef 12 is a major version change, which state there's probably breaking changes...

A lot of communication have been made on chef.io blog, take time to read about it before giving it a try, you'll save time.

Comment: I created the admin and organization. I configured knife.rb. Somehow, its shooting up a new error when i try to check the node/clients.
**knife node list**
ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: testvm3.domain.co.in - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
ERROR: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Comment: See [this](https://docs.chef.io/chef_client_security.html#changes-prior-to-chef-12) and so [this too](http://docs.chef.io/install_dk.html#get-ssl-certificates)

Comment: It seems like EVERYONE gets SSL validation errors with chef server 12.  Just do a quick google for `chef 12 ssl validation` and I'm sure you'll find plenty of help.

Comment: @Tensibai, @Tejay : I had followed the steps for ssl certification verification with knife ssl fetch and check. It shows output as desired.
But, when i say "knife client/node list" , i get an xml response, i wonder whats going wrong :( 
`ERROR: The object you are looking for could not be found
Response: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-sransitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
...
... </html>`

Comment: Do you have a node registered to this server ? If not it's normal it can not give a list...

Comment: @ripevik did u find any solution for that issue ..?? . even i getting that while uploading cookbook or seeing client/node list. Even i am getting an xml response.

Comment: @Mohan: i guess you have to check for the correct entries in the knife.rb file. the chef server entry : **chef-server.domain.com/org-name/client**
and the other changes as well. The knife.rb will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

admin.pem is nothing but the clients pem file.

whenever you bootstrap the node using knife command. client.pem or admin.pem or node.pem file is automatically generated under /etc/chef/client.pem