# Configuring chef-server-12 to work with ip-address and not fqdn

Tags: chef-infra

The official documentation mentions in the prerequisites that: ***"A resolvable hostname that is specified using a FQDN or an IP address"***  is required.
I can even see that the certificates are also generated based on fqdn.

However, I want to know if is it possible to install/configure chef-server 12.x using ip-address ? (This was possible in chef-server-version 11.x)

I want all the communication to chef-server happening via ip-address and not via fqdn. 
e.g. chef-server_url in my knife.rb should look like below:

https://chef_server-ip-address/organizations/org-name

Comment: That sounds counterproductive at best... I'm unsure it could work or not, did you try it and encounter a problem ? SO is not a free code service nor a consulting service. We're happy to help when a reasonable effort trying to solve the problem yourself is show, I don't see this here.

Answer (score 0):

Chef 12 has a couple of backwardly incompatible changes, but once understood I have had no issues with the upgrade. (For legacy reasons I still use both Chef 11 and Chef 12)

One biggie that has caused problems is that fact that SSL verification is switched on by default. While this is a good thing it does cause problems, like the fact that certs are rarely granted to IP addresses...

The following answer illustrates how to setup a chef workstation for both Chef 11 and Chef 12:

[To setup chef workstation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21700194/to-setup-chef-workstation/21712350#21712350)

I hope it helps.